# jQuery to make photos bigger doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have part of jQuery code that makes my photos bigger. It works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome or Opera, but if I use whichever IE it doesn't work and I can't find which part of this code isn't compatible with IE (I think this is a problem), so I don't know how to find solution (if some solution is possible of course)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Moje portfolio</title>
<meta content="Ewa, Makowska, strony www, grafika komputerowa" name="keywords">
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
/*show bigger picture*/
function showit(src){
    document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML = "<img src="+src+" id='bigimg' />";

$('#mask').css('display','block');
$('#mask').animate({'width':screen.width,'height':screen.height +100, opacity:'0.5'});

$('#fixed').css('display','block');
var bigimg = document.getElementById("bigimg");

$('#picture').css('display','block');
$('#picture').animate({
    width: bigimg.width,
    height:bigimg.height});

$('#close').css('display','block'); 
}

function closeit(){
$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#close').css('display','none');
    $('#fixed').css('display','none');
    $('#picture').css('display','none');
    $('#mask').css('display','none');
})

$('#fixed').click(function(){
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $('#mask').css('display','none');
    $('#picture').css('display','none');
    $('#close').css('display','none');
})
}

        $('.smallimages').hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().css({'border':'1px solid #666699'});
            },function(){
            $(this).stop().css('border', 'none');
        });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id ="close" onClick="closeit();"></div>
<div id="mask"></div>
<div id="fixed"><div id="picture"></div></div>
<div id="insidetext">

<?php
function listfile($dir)
{
$tab=array();
$handle=opendir($dir);
while ($file = readdir($handle)){
if($file=='.'||$file=='..' || is_dir($dirname.$file)) continue;
array_push($tab,$file);}
closedir($handle);
return $tab;
}

$tab=listfile('gallery');
foreach($tab as $value)
{
echo '<img src="gallery/'.$value.'"
onClick="showit(`gallery/'.$value.'`)" class="smallimages" />';
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have two versions of jQuery being loaded?

Comment: Your code does not work because you are trying to access elements before they are rendered to the page. It is like eating a sandwich before you make it. Learn about document.ready. Run that code in Chrome or Firefox and it also should not work.

Comment: You have two versions of jQuery, and as far as I know, IE doesn't like it when you change CSS  (your `height` and `width` values in `$().animate()`)variables without having a unit on the value (px, em, rem, etc.). And what epascarello said ^^^

Comment: Firstly open your browser console in order to debug code

Comment: change `onClick` to `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all answer very much. Then I removed second version of jquery console showed me where was a problem. IE has problem with this `(small tilde?), and work with \'. So than I change 
"showit(`gallery/'.$value.'`) to  "showit(\'gallery/'.$value.'\')"
everything is perfect.